# Need the name for a URL that contains lots of garbage expect the name. (Advanced BASH)

Tags: bash, url, wget, identify

http://romhustler.net/file/54654/RFloRzkzYjBxeUpmSXhmczJndVZvVXViV3d2bjExMUcwRmdhQzltaU5UUTJOVFE2TVRrM0xqZzNMakV4TXk0eU16WTZNVE01TXpnME1UZ3pPRHBtYVc1aGJGOWtiM2R1Ykc5aFpGOXNhVzVy <-- Url that needs to be identified

http://romhustler.net/rom/ps2/final-fantasy-x-usa <-- Parent url

If you copy paste this url you will see the browser identify the files name. How can I get a bash script to do the same ?

I need to WGET the first URL, but because it will be for 100 more items i cant copy paste each URL.

I currently have the menu set up for all the files. Just dont know how to mass download each file individually as the URL's for the files have no matching patterns.

*Bits of my working menu:

```
                    #Raw gamelist grabber
    w3m http://romhustler.net/roms/ps2 |cat|egrep "/5" > rawmenu.txt

                    #splits initial file into a files(games01) that contain 10 lines.
                    #-d puts lists files with 01
    split -l 10 -d rawmenu.txt games

                    #s/ /_/g - replaces spaces with underscore
                    #s/__.*//g - removes anything after two underscores
    select opt in\
    $(cat games0$num|sed -e 's/ /_/g' -e 's/__.*//g')\
    "Next"\
    "Quit" ;

    if [[ "$opt" =~ "${lines[0]}" ]];
    then
        ### Here the URL needs to be grabbed ###
```

This has to be done is BASH. Is this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that romhustler.net use some Javascript on thier full download pages to hide the final download link for a few seconds after the page loads, possibly to prevent this kind of web scraping.

However, if they were using direct links to ZIP files for example, we could do this:

```
# Use curl to get the HTML of the page and egrep to match the hyperlinks to each ROM
curl -s http://romhustler.net/roms/ps2 | egrep -o "rom/ps2/[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+" > rawmenu.txt

# Loop through each of those links and extract the full download link
while read LINK
do
    # Extract full download link
    FULLDOWNLOAD=`curl -s "http://romhustler.net$LINK" | egrep -o "/download/[0-9]+/[a-zA-Z0-9]+"`
    # Download the file
    wget "http://romhustler.net$FULLDOWNLOAD"
done < "rawmenu.txt"
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Are you saying that there is no way other way of doing it expect for decrypting the Javascript ? But even that will be impossible ?

Comment: In order to get the final download URL you'll need a CLI browser capable of executing the Javascript on the page. A quick search threw up http://phantomjs.org/ but I think you could also (theoretically) use the Webkit engine. From a quick analysis of the page it appears the download link is obtained from an AJAX request.